# ImportError.But i could run the **.py in command line,i couldn't run it in Pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, importerror

I create a virtual env by anaconda and conda,then I have tried import the `pandas`

But the error I am getting:

> File "E:/Py/Pynet/Pydata/d01.py", line 8, in 
>       import pandas as pd
>       File "G:\Kits\Sword\Anaconda\envs\env4\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 19, in 
>       "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
>       ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy'],

the same code that i run have no problem in command line,but it have bug as above in pycharm,
why does the happen?

Answer (score 1):

You need to point Pycharm to your virtualenv. See the official docs for more details: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html.

Comment: I have point Pycharm to my virtualenv,but,I cant' fixed it,and an other pc avoid the problem